# Using JAR inside a jar

Tags: java

I created a JAR file from my java project.
Using Eclipse, I added a JAR as a referenced library in my own project.
However, now when I try to run my program's JAR using `java -jar myProgram.jar`, I get an exception stating that my referenced jar is not available.

So how can I create a JAR consisting a reference to a different JAR and make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Eclipse's runnable JAR exporter. Since Eclipse 3.5 you've the following options when you rightclick project, choose *Export > Runnable JAR file*:

[image]

Either way, Eclipse should take care that you'll be able to run the JAR the way you want on the exported location.

Answer (score 5):

Right, an executable JAR cannot contain its own JAR dependencies.

You have to have the main class and classpath set in the executable JAR manifest, then package all your JAR dependencies along with the executable JAR in a relative directory structure that matches the manifest CLASSPATH.  Reading [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip127.html) might help.

Answer (score 2):

See `jarjar` project. It is exactly  what you are looking for. http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/